# Setting relative path in SublimeLinter's sublimelinter_executable_map

Tags: path, sublimetext2, relative-path, sublimelinter

**Setup:** Portable editions of `Sublime Text 2` with its plugin `Sublimelinter` and `node.exe`.

`sublimelinter_executable_map` has to set in a way so that `Sublimelinter` uses `node.exe` as JavaScript engine.

**Could one do this using a relative path instead of a fully qualified path?**

Trying with different forms of relative paths as given in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths), the plugin failed to detect `node.exe`. The console message i got was `SublimeLinter: javascript disabled (One of the following JavaScript engines must be installed: node.js, JavaScriptCore)`

Comment: Windows shortcuts and start menu entries can set the working directory of the Sublime Text executable. If any paths are relative, I guess they are relative to this working directory. You can confirm from SublimeLinter source code if the plugin allows relative path inputs: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GitHub issue on this topic:

- https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/612

Is a duplicate of these:

- https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/611
- https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/459

This seems to be a hot topic.

I forked the repository and started to code a patch for you, which seems to center around this segment:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/blob/4ef4b2ca08e0224b8af59bf3406c4927432efb94/sublimelinter/modules/base_linter.py#L380

But then, it dawned on me... **environment variables**. Since this seems to be a prevalent issue with many unsolved requests, it seems that you ought to set the `PATH` environment variable, and place the location you are looking to be found first, earlier in that variable.

Don't know your Windows version, and the process to set an environment variable will be different for your version, so you ought to experiment with that, and then use that method as the standard for all your environments ( as it seems implied you have more than one to maintain ).

**Update:** Ruby seems to allow relative paths, but JavaScript does not, because of this section:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/blob/4ef4b2ca08e0224b8af59bf3406c4927432efb94/sublimelinter/modules/base_linter.py#L380

Which hinges on: `JAVASCRIPT_ENGINE_WRAPPERS_PATH`

So the answer is, unless that code is adapted, no. Relative paths cannot be used for JS.

Comment: PATHS are good but since this is a portable setup, i am interested in using relative paths inside 'sublimelinter_executable_map'